# How to use UnsafePointer in vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888() using Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried to rewrite [RNFrostedSidebar](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar) using Swift but I met a problem.

At line 99 ~ 101 in [RNFrostedSidebar.m](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar/blob/master/RNFrostedSidebar.m) ,

```
func vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(_ src: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>, 
    _ dest: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>,  
    _ tempBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    _ srcOffsetToROI_X: vImagePixelCount,
    _ srcOffsetToROI_Y: vImagePixelCount,
    _ kernel_height: UInt32,
    _ kernel_width: UInt32,
    _ backgroundColor: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>,
    _ flags: vImage_Flags) -> vImage_Error
```

function `vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(...)` requires a UnsafePointer, I tried to use `effectInBuffer` or `&effectInBuffer` but not worked.

Using `effectInBuffer` as parameter would lead to `'vImage_Buffer' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>'` error. But in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_14), it seems to be valid.

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you show how you declared `effectInBuffer` and `effectOutBuffer`? As long as you've declared them as mutable, using the `&` prefix should work.

Comment: @NateCook Like this: `let effectInBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data:CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext), height:CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext), width:CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext), rowBytes:CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to declare any variables that are going to be passed as `UnsafePointer` or `UnsafeMutablePointer` as mutable. That is, use `var` instead of `let` in the declaration:

```
var effectInBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data:CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext), 
    height:CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext),
    width:CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext),
    rowBytes:CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext))
```

And then prefix with `&` in your function call:

```
vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, ...)
```

You'll need to do this for the `source`, `dest`, `tempBuffer`, and `backgroundColor` parameters.